# Oracle NoSQL Error : [ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT] PUT: Illegal Argument: Value should not be set for a generated always identity column: id

Tags: oracle-nosql

I’m trying to update a row with the Node sdk and I keep getting `Error: NoSQLArgumentError: [ILLEGAL_ARGUMENT] PUT: Illegal Argument: Value should not be set for a generated always identity column: id.`

What am I doing wrong here?

```
async function update(id, data, table)
{
    var timestamp = new Date
    res = await client.putIfPresent(table, {
        id: id,
        last_modified: timestamp,
        json_document: data
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created this "*Answer your own question*" because the first time dealing with this error, I've decided to change ALL my code in order to use the SQL API and so use the UPDATE command. I was thinking that it was the only solution

*It appears that you have created a table with an identity column for the field "id" and that you used "generate always." In this case, when you perform a put operation there must be no value set for "id" or you will get this error. Further, if you are trying to update (vs create) an existing row with an identity column you cannot use put() at all but must instead use an update query*

In fact, We can use the command putIfPresent if the table was created using `generate by default`. In this case, the previous constraints will not apply

Oracle NoSQL supports the following options :

- GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY
- GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY
- GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL AS IDENTITY

Depending your requirements, this is interesting to know